# Store telephone records efficiently

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Suppose you have a repository of a million records of mobile numbers.            How will you store these numbers so that you can check whether a given number already exists in minimum space and time complexity?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Trie data structure. 
following link should be helpful 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18033/Phone-Directory-Implementation-Using-TRIE

Comment: Beware that a trie can be very memory hungry. Like 40 bytes per stored digit, i.e. 360 bytes per number ! A hash table will be more compact and as efficient. Also consider encoding the numbers as a single integer (4 bytes instead of 9). With such an encoding, a hash table is definitely faster.

Comment: Tries are only "space efficient" in certain cases. Traversing pointer structures is also slower in real hardware (due to cache misses) than theory would make you think.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on maximum phone number digits `d`, you can use a (large) bitset where bit *i* is true iff phone *i* is present: one single check and you're done. That would **minimize time complexity**, especially if you go on and test this on a machine where the bit-set fits in main memory (tries are O(digits) - this would be O(1)).

If you want to **minimize space complexity**, and `10^d` >> `n` (with n = number of phones stored), simply storing the phones in a sorted array would be more compact than building a traditional trie (tries have lots of pointers: overhead). Binary search would still be in the same complexity class (O(digits) is O(log n)) as using a trie.

Another option is to build [bloom filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) - they have **strong space advantages over tries**, do not involve pointer overhead, and by building a positive-filter and a negative-filter you get 100% precision and recall. Retrieval may be a bit slower than with other options, but theoretically speaking, it would still be in the same complexity class.

*Questions such as this one have way too much wiggle room. Without more details, talking of a "best" storage makes no sense*. Also, in 95% of cases, a language-library-provided set will be good-enough. 1M entries are not that many.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary or hash map will serve very well here. Memory consumption is O(n), where n is the number of items to be stored. In .NET that O(n) includes a constant that's on the order of 25 or so. So a million phone numbers will require about 25 MB of indexing overhead. But checking for existence is O(1).

Contrast that to a trie, which is likely more memory hungry (40 or more bytes per node), and whose lookup time is O(k), where k is the number of characters in the item you're looking up.

It might pay to give the low-tech solution a try, too: a simple sorted array and a binary search. This is going to give you the smallest memory footprint, and a binary search on a million items is pretty darned fast with modern hardware. You don't say what your required throughput is, but if you're doing, say, a thousand or so lookups per second, the binary search will definitely fit the bill. It might be worth your while to code it up and profile it. Why go for "the fastest" if the simple solution is fast enough?